# R plot - different color for defined number of rows

Tags: r, plot

I have a simple data in two columns and 300 rows as:

```
 P1         P2
-0.0319     0.00108078  
0.111993    0.000131346
0.117388    -0.0141524
0.117025    0.106717
```

I have created a simple plot using the very basic plot function:

```
data <- read.table("data_file", header = TRUE)  
plot(data$P1,data$P2, pch=16, col=rainbow(15))
```

This gave a plot consisting of 300 dots (as number of rows are 300 in data) where the color is repeated after every 15 dots. But I require that `the initial 20 dots should appear of same color, then next 20 of other color, and so on`. It is pertinent to mention here that these is no category for the data, just to group the dots of plot based on the number of rows.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rep` and `colors` in case your data increases afterwards.

```
  myCol <- rep(colors()[1:15],each=20)      # Define your color Palette
  plot(data$P1,data$P2, pch=16, col=myCol)  # Use the color Palette
```

To know more about color list: use `colors()`and change the above `[1:15]` to replace your 15 colors.

```
  colors()            # The color list having 657 colors
  colors()[16:30]     # Choose any 15 you require by providing index b/w 1 and 657
  colors()[601:615]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a call to [`rep()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html) passing the `each` argument:

```
plot(data$P1,data$P2,pch=16L,col=rep(rainbow(15L),each=20L));
```